# Can we use our own method to directly pass url with parameters to login yammer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, yammer

I want to login to Yammer using my website credentials. Whenever I login to my website I must be logged in to Yammer to view the feed.

Is this possible or is there any API for automatically logging in a user?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to automatically authenticate users to the Yammer Embed feed for various reasons, including the modes that are supported for authentication to Yammer today and security. Depending on how the Yammer network and the O365 identity configuration is setup, you may be able to improve the experience.